# avoid writing nothing to file

Tags: python, grep

I am using Python and also using egrep to pick out certain lines and create a .txt file with those lines in:

```
os.system('cat {0}|egrep " {1}."|egrep " 7..\."|egrep " 8..\." >> {2}_{1}_800.tim' .format(full,epoch,pname))
```

The extra part that I'm not sure how to do is that if there are NO matching lines, I don't want a blank .txt file to be written.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use pure python?

Comment: What happens if you put a `|| rm {2}_{1}_800.tim` at the end of the command?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you can use some if statements, if I'm not mistaken.

```
grep "my pattern" input-file.txt | {
  FILE=output-file.txt
  read x; #Read the first line
  if ! [[ $x ]]; then
    exit #If the 1st line was empty, then there is no match
  fi
  echo $x >> $FILE
  while read line; do
    echo $x
  done >> $FILE
}
```

This should work just fine. Now, you can just write this

```
'cat {0}|egrep " {1}."|egrep " 7..\."|egrep " 8..\." | 'cat {0}|egrep " {1}."|egrep " 7..\." | egrep " 8..\." | {   FILE={2}_{1}_800.tim;   read x;   if ! [[ $x ]]; then     exit;   fi;   echo $x >> $FILE;   while read line; do     echo $x;   done >> $FILE; }
```